# how to reserve time for char(10) type objects

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, schedule

`Postgresql 9.2` reservation table contains `objekt2` column whose type is `char(10)`.

The following code is used to create non-overlapped reservations table:

```
CREATE TABLE reservat (
  id serial primary key,
  objekt2 char(10) references yksus2,
  during tsrange,
  rida int references rid on delete cascade not null,
  EXCLUDE USING gist (objekt2 text_pattern_ops WITH =, during WITH &&)
);
```

This causes error:

> ERROR:  operator class "text_pattern_ops" does not exist for access
>   method "gist"

How to fix this error so that `char(10)` type columns can used for reservations and overlapping reservations are not allowed for same `objekt2` values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [btree_gist](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/btree-gist.html) extension. There is an example in the docs about this: [Constraints on Ranges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT)